# Setting color for textview dynamically using spinner?

Tags: android, xml

I want to create one textview, the colour of that text is to be changed by the user by selecting colour from spinner object.

The spinner object contains list of colours, that is options for user to change the colour of textview dynamically.

Excuse for my english and help me out..

Comment: can you please post some code from ur end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textview"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="TextView"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<array name="colorname">
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>Pink</item>
</array>

<array name="colorcode">
    <item>#FF0000</item>
    <item>#ffff00</item>
    <item>#00ff00</item>
    <item>#0000ff</item>
    <item>#FF0080</item>
</array>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinner;
    private TextView textview;
    private ArrayList<String> colorNameList;
    private ArrayList<String> colorCodeList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        colorNameList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorname)));
        colorCodeList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorcode)));

        final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colorNameList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colorCodeList.get(position)));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you... Can you please approve and upvote this ans if is usefult to you ?

Comment: Is this possible to give items from xml file to colorList and colorMap ..??

Answer (score 0):

```
YourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
        {
           YourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
            // your code here

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

It would be nice if you've tried searching on Stack Site.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView text;
private Spinner spin;
ArrayList al;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
al=new ArrayList();
al.add("RED");
al.add("BLUE");
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,al);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg2)
        {
        case 0:
            text.setText("srikanth");
            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case 1:
            text.setText("SRIkANTH BLUE");
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});


}
```

}

***I hope it helps you***