# accessing item name in string-array (Android)

Tags: android, xml

this is my code in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="day_array">
    <item name="sh">Sunday</item>
    <item name="ye">Monday</item>
    <item name="do">Tuesday</item>
    <item name="se">Wednesday</item>
    <item name="ch">Thursday</item>
</string-array>
    <string-array name="time_array">
    <item name="00">00:00</item>
    <item name="01">01:00</item>
    <item name="02">02:00</item>
    <item name="03">03:00</item>
    <item name="04">04:00</item>
    <item name="05">05:00</item>
    <item name="06">06:00</item>
    <item name="07">07:00</item> 
    <item name="08">08:00</item>
    <item name="09">09:00</item>
    <item name="10">10:00</item>
    <item name="11">11:00</item>
    <item name="12">12:00</item>
    <item name="13">13:00</item>
    <item name="14">14:00</item>
    <item name="15">15:00</item>
    <item name="16">16:00</item>
    <item name="17">17:00</item>
    <item name="18">18:00</item>
    <item name="19">19:00</item>
    <item name="20">20:00</item>
    <item name="21">21:00</item>
    <item name="22">22:00</item>
    <item name="23">23:00</item>
    <item name="24">24:00</item>
</string-array>
```

and then in my layout i have two Spinner:

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/roozlist"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/day_array" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/timelist"
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/time_array" />
```

what i want to do, is that, if the user chooses Sunday in "roozlist" and  08:00 in "timelist", and then he clicked on a button, i want the "sh08" to be returnd, in fact the name of each item he clicked, how can i assess to the name attribute on each item in my string-array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take two more string array for selected day and time respective value :

```
<string-array name="day_array">
   <item>Sunday</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="day_array_value">
  <item>sh</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="time_array_value">
  <item>00</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="time_array">
  <item>00:00</item>
</string-array>
```

Initialize value array :

```
 String[] roozArrayValue = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.day_array_value);
 String[] timeArrayValue = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_array_value);
```

Get spinner selected item respective value from value array:

```
String value = roozArrayValue[roozlist.getSelectedItemPosition()]+timeArrayValue[timelist.getSelectedItemPosition()]
```

Check Example : [Spinner String item value get (not string name) android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098359/spinner-string-item-value-get-not-string-name-android/26098459#26098459)

Answer (score 1):

try these one

initialize some variable

```
String[] day;
String[] time;
```

and in your onCreate method

```
day = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.day_array);
time = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_array);
```

and then on your onClickButton

```
String out = day[roozlist.getSelectedItemPosition()]+""+time[timelist.getSelectedItemPosition()];
```