# How to set selected item of Spinner by value, not by position

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

```
<item value="245">Guinea-Bissau [245]</item >
<item value="592">Guyana [592]</item >
<item value="509">Haiti  [509]</item >
<item value="504">Honduras [504]</item >
<item value="91">India [91]</item >
<item value="62">Indonesia [62]</item >
```

> I am using this

```
country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //selectioncountry = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        selectionarea = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
});
```

> this code give thie value of india is 4 but i need 91 how can i do
>   this ???

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057400/accessing-item-name-in-string-array-android/27057930#27057930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take one more string array for selected country respective value :

```
<string-array name="country">
   <item>India</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="country_value">
  <item>91</item>
</string-array>
```

Initialize value array :

```
String[] countryValue = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_value);
```

Get spinner selected item respective value from value array:

```
selectionarea = countryValue[position];
```

Check Example : [accessing item name in string-array (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057400/accessing-item-name-in-string-array-android/27057930#27057930)

Answer (score 8):

```
private void selectSpinnerValue(Spinner spinner, String myString)
     {
         int index = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++){
             if(spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals(myString)){
                 spinner.setSelection(i);
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this. it will work fine.

```
int position = adapter.getPosition(value);
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < country.getCount(); i++){
    if(country.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals("yourString")){
        country.setSelection(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

You could also solve it by this way, by specifiying the `String` you are searching for instead if you have access to it. Otherwise, you will have to follow Haresh Chhelana's approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override [`getItemId(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int)) to return the value instead of the position id which is the default