# How to get Value and display member of spinner in android and not itempostion?

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to assign an ID and a Name to spinner in Android. I then want to get back the value of the ID and the Name of the spinner. How can I get both values back?

Comment: You question is too broad. Can you show us the code that you've already got?

Comment: Please show what have you tried and add some code

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122120/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position/27122251#27122251

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and unclear. But I think you want to get a name value pair (where names are the items in spinner). Here are some useful methods

To get selected item (String) from spinner

```
mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

To get selected item position

```
mSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

To get selected item ID

```
mSpinner.getSelectedItemId();
```

Now, for your Name-value pair, keep your names and values (names and IDs) in a `HashMap`.
 In `onItemSelected(...)` of Spinner, get the selected name by 
`Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()`
 and you can find the value (ID) assigned to it from HashMap by 
`String mID = mHashMap.get("name")`

Now you have both name and ID of selected item.